# PostgreSQL pg_dump --disable-triggers only effective when dumping data only?

Tags: postgresql

`--disable-triggers` option has effect only when using `--data-only`.

I cannot figure out why I shouldn't be allowed to disable triggers with a full database dump. In my case I want to restore data without triggers.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of `--disable-triggers` is *not* to permanently disable the triggers in the database, but only to disable them while data are being loaded. With a full dump, the triggers are created *after* the data have been loaded, so there is no reason to disable any triggers.